# Limit theorem in Gut's Probability: A graduate course

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand the proof of Theorem 3.1 in *Probability: A graduate course*.
[image]
The notation with the diagonal arrows was previously introduced to mean that a sequence of sets is non-decreasing/non-increasing towards the limit ($A$) after the arrow. I assume the application of the same diagonal arrow to probabilities is then meant to signify just taking a normal limit? But I am not sure.

When I translate the last line to how I understand it, I get

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(\sum_{k=1}^n B_k) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k) = \lim_{n \to \infty}  P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k) =P(A)
$$

I'm not sure if that is right. If it is, I don't understand how we can just do the last step. If you can just take the limit inside the probability measure, why not just do that in the first step and be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

In $$
P(A_n) =  \sum_{k=1}^n P(B_k) \uparrow  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(B_k) =  P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k) =P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)=P(A)
$$ the first equality is by additivity, second equality is by countable additivity, third equality follows from the fact that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ and the last equality is because $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k=A$.

Comment: I understand these points, but I don't get what happens to the limit that we are taking.

Comment: Once you get to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(B_k)$ **no limits are involved**.  You are mis-intrepreting the argument. The main point is everything has to be proved from countable additivity of a probability measure. You cannot just pass to limits the way you have written.  You have written $\lim_{n \to \infty}  P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k) =P(A)$ but this is not the argument; this is what we want to prove. 
 @ari

Comment: But in order to go from $\sum_{k=1}^n P(B_k)$ to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(B_k)$ we are taking the limit $n \to \infty$, right? I find it confusing that we are doing that basically in the middle of the equation and I also don't understand why we can do it to $\sum_{k=1}^n P(B_k)$ but not to $P(A_n)$. I do see the point on countable additivity! Just what happens before is confusing me.

Comment: I agree that the last step in my 'translation' is what we want to prove! That's why I'm asking; what am I misinterpreting in the notation that makes my translation different to what they mean in the proof?

Comment: You have to follow exactly what I have written in my answer without bringing in those limits.  @ari